# what is worng with me? bubblesort about string

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void bubblesort(int n, char *ptr[]){
    char *tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){    
        for (int j = 0 ; j < n; j++){
            if(strcmp(*(ptr+i) , *(ptr+j))>0){
                strcpy(tmp , *(ptr+i));
                strcpy(*(ptr+i) , *(ptr+j));
                strcpy(*(ptr+j) , tmp);
            }
        }
    }
     //printf("\n",ptr+0,ptr+1,ptr+2,ptr+3,ptr+4,ptr+5,ptr+6,ptr+7,ptr+8,ptr+9); **<= without this line my code doesn't executive**
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d\n", &n);
    char str[10][20];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 gets(str[i]);
    char *ptr[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        ptr[i] = str[i];
    bubblesort(n, ptr);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        puts(ptr[i]);
}
```

C:\Users\kk\Desktop\C>a
10
banana
kiwi
apple
tomato
lemon
melon
pear
blueberry
strawberry
orange

tomato
strawberry
pear
orange
melon
lemon
kiwi
blueberry
banana
apple

C:\Users\kk\Desktop\C>

with out above line

C:\Users\kk\Desktop\C>a
10
banana
kiwi
apple
tomato
lemon
melon
pear
blueberry
strawberry
orange

C:\Users\kk\Desktop\C>
`

Comment: `char *tmp;` -- Where does this point to?  This is uninitialized, yet you are writing characters to that location, wherever it is.  Pointers must point somewhere valid before you can use them like the way you're using `tmp`.

Comment: Don't use `gets`.  The man page even tells you not to.

Comment: Also, don't write `*(ptr+i)`.  Just write `ptr[i]`.  Don't fight the language.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie actually I'm not good at C especially pointer. may I ask you how and what can I initialize 'char *tmp;'? I don't know even why I have to initialize 'char *tmp;'

Comment: @TomKarzes thank you for your advice but this problem is only about implementing bubblesort, so I can't touch gets which in the main function.

Comment: Time to read [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/3422102)

Comment: The point of pointers (in this case, the pointers to strings) is that the objects don't need to be shifted; just rearrange (sort) the pointers in the array... Replace those `strcpy()` calls with swapping pointers (and go read the explanation of the bubble sort algorithm.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. The inner loop should use `j` and `j + 1` not `i` and `j`, and the condition on `j` for that loop is incorrect.
2. As you are operating on pointers to string you can just swap those instead of copying the strings themselves.  It's clearer to write that `swap()` function instead of doing it inline.
3. Finally, `gets()` is a not safe to use, and for these types of problems it's much better to hard-code a test case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap(char **a, char **b) {
    char *tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

void bubblesort(size_t n, char *ptr[n]) {
    if(n < 2) return;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
            if(strcmp(ptr[j], ptr[j + 1]) > 0)
                swap(&ptr[j], &ptr[j + 1]);
}

int main() {
    char *a[] = {
        "Lorem",
        "ipsum",
        "dolor",
        "sit",
        "amet"
    };
    size_t n = sizeof a / sizeof *a;
    bubblesort(n, a);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        puts(a[i]);
}
```

and here is the output:

```
Lorem
amet
dolor
ipsum
sit
```